# Document the custom API response with Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on an API with Spring-boot, and the documentation was done with RestDocs. However, I am testing Swagger.

With swagger, I found problems documenting the API methods responses.

I have an object called Response, which is the ResponseEntity type in which I return the responses. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ApiOperation(value = "Add a new Resource")
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful operation"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request")
    @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")
})
ResponseEntity<Response> createResource(Resource resource){
    // ...
    try{
        // ...
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Response().addObject("resource", resource));
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(new Response().addObject("error", "can't process request"));
    }
}
```

Response object:

```
    public class Response {

    private HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    public Response() {
        reset();
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public Response addObject(String key, Object object) {
        response.put(key, object);
        return this;
    }

    public Response reset() {
        response.clear();
        response.put("timestamp", new Date());
        return this;
    } 
}
```

Resource:

```
@Entity(name = "resource")
@Table(name = "resource")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
@ApiModel(value = "Resource", description = "A resource")
public class Resource {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The database generated loyappty ID", readOnly = true)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Resource name", required = true)
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @NotNull
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Resource name", required = true)
    private Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();

    //...
    //Getters, Setters & other methods
    // ...

}
```

The problem is that Swagger is not documenting the answer correctly.

[image here with Swagger response doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4Ixc.png)

An this is the real response:

```
{
    "response" : {
        "resource" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "Dummy resource",
            "info" : {
                "type" : "X",
                "owner" : "me"
            }
        },
        "timestamp": "2018-11-28T20:01:51.663+0000"
    }
}
```

I think my confusion is that my Response object actually contains a HashMap , and Swagger does not know what that HashMap contains. In this case that Map will contain:

**<"resource", Resource>, <"timestamp", Date>**

Do you know what may be happening or how to solve it?

can you help me? Thank you.